# Using Python libraries in Racket

Tags: python, racket, ffi

Can I use Python code and libraries in Racket?  I have installed PyonR (https://github.com/pedropramos/PyonR) in DrRacket so I can choose "#lang python" and run Python code. But how can I combine Racket and Python language codes for my application?

There is also a limited Python to Lisp translator at https://github.com/nurv/pnil . Is there something similar for Racket?

---

Edit: As advised in comments, I tried following. This python code in file "pysamples.rkt" works well in DrRacket:

```
#lang python

def greet(name):
    print 'Hello', name

greet('Alfred')
```

Output:

```
Hello Alfred
```

I tried using above definition in Racket code, but it did not work. Following is the Racket code:

```
#lang racket
; (require python/config) (enable-cpyimport!) ; ran this once; worked.

(#%require "pysamples.rkt")
(greet "Racket_code")
```

The error is:

```
greet: unbound identifier in module in: greet
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but does `cpyimport` do what you want?

Comment: But that seems to be for using Racket modules in Python. Can I import Python modules for use in Racket code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PyonR project is the closest ready-to-use way of using Python libraries from Racket that I know of. However note that there is a difference between Python libraries written in Python and Python libraries that are a thin Python layer on top of a C library. As you have experienced the latter type is not working (to my knowledge at least - but Pedro is the one to ask).

If you need to use a library written in language X (for X could be Python) you can always write a "listener" program in language X that waits for messages from a Racket program, and when a message is received, computes an answer and sends it back to the Racket program. How to send and receive messages is up to you, but a simple option is to have two files, one "R-to-X" which Racket writes to and X reads from, and another "X-to-R" where Racket receives the messages.

This approach has some overhead, but if the computation takes longer than sending the message, then it is a viable solution.

Comment: Is there any real advantage of using DrRacket with "#lang python" ?  What is the advantage over using python in any other editor? (I am not asking about advantages of DrRacket as an editor).

Comment: How does one `"wait for messages from a Racket program"`, say in python?

Answer (score 4):

[Accoring to the readme](https://github.com/pedropramos/PyonR) you can import python 2.7 packages, but you need to use `cpyimport`. One of the examples looks like this:

```
#lang python
cpyimport numpy as np
from "racket" import time

    def add_arrays(n):
        result = np.zeros((100,100))
        for i in range(n):
            result += np.random.randint(0, 100000, (100,100))
        return result

    print time(add_arrays(10000))
```

Looking at the code, a pure python library you could just import give that it's in rackets paths and was given `#lang python` top line. all defined are always exported.

Comment: If above file is named mypy.rkt, can I include this file in my racket code files using "(#%require "mypy.rkt")" to use all numpy functions there?

Comment: cpyimport got enabled from Racket all right. But then when I tried running above code, DrRacket crashes and closes. The occurs every time I try it with above code.

Comment: On running from command line: $ racket mypy.rkt , I get following error: SIGSEGV MAPERR si_code 1 fault on addr 0x4 , Aborted

Comment: Re: cpyimport crashes Racket, are you on OS X? If you are this is a known bug: https://github.com/pedropramos/PyonR/issues/8

Comment: Then please submit a bugreport to the PyonR project.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers and comments addressed difficulties with certain Python libraries, but if you're just interested in using a function from a pure Python file in a Racket module, try something like this:

In file "greetings.py":

```
#lang python

def greet(name):
    print 'Hello', name
```

In Racket:

```
#lang racket

(require python)
(py-import "greetings" as python-module)

(py-method-call python-module "greet" "Racket")
```